# Does anyone use Madoko to write LaTeX documents or this is an "evolutionary" impass

Tags: markdown, git, katex

I've stumbled upon [Madoko](https://www.madoko.net/) that *merges* markdown and LaTeX features into a kind of markdown syntax beefed up   with $\LaTeX$ superpowers for maths, structuring, x-references, bibliography, etc.

I am quite impressed with the syntax.

Still, if no one uses it, if the project is dead (of which I am not sure), it feels a lot to "master" just for a cleaner markup language than plain TeX/LaTeX, 'org-mode', 'markdown' with another addon such as 'R markdown' or [markdown-katex](https://github.com/mbarkhau/markdown-katex) which looks great and boast to be rendred natively in GitLab but unfortunately not github--  and others.

My primary need was for github markdown to interpret some LaTeX *syntax on the fly* ; but may be I was dreaming of another world where all tex markups were playing well with each other !

edited: to answer some comments the website seems to have changed to http://madoko.org/reference.html

Comment: Do you have a link for Modoko? A quick web search did not result in anything for me.

Comment: @Marijn I gues this is meant https://www.madoko.net/

Comment: I tried it, pretty slow...

Comment: Just curiosity: What you dislike of Rmarkdown? Maybe is the most complete markdown flavors,  it can include raw LaTeX just inserting the code, beside it that also can include  chunks of R, python, bash, etc. Moreover, now Rstudio  have a visual mode to use it mostly like a  WYSIWYM editor, can even make a bibtex bibliography easily, etc. So, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Tried to add the new website, but it seems this is only the doc and the moloko.net address is down. @Fran I will stick with Rmd when needed; the only major thing I dislike is it's poor adoption (but the trend is going up)

Comment: @Samusz But actually what I suggest now is Quarto, that is the successor of Rmarkdown. Is ratter similar, so it is easy transform the .Rmd in .qmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> may be I was dreaming of another world where all tex markups were playing well with each other !

This world already exists, with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) :) Whether Madoko is worth your time is something only you can answer, but if what you're looking for is

> markdown and LaTeX features into a kind of markdown syntax beefed up with $\LaTeX$ superpowers for maths, structuring, x-references, bibliography, etc.

*and* you want the benefits of a sizeable ecosystem, lots of features and plugins, etc., you won't go wrong with pandoc.